# NeoPixel library slow with large number of WS2812B LEDs (Raspi3)

Tags: led, python-3, ws2812

Noob here, I am currently working with a 10m long strip of 144LED/m density LEDs. The problem is with such a high number of LEDs loops (like a color wipe for example or filling LEDs one after another) take forever. I want to find a way to use the same format of pixel[i] = (r,g,b)... Is there a way to have it react faster. I tried splitting up the strip and tried to control it from multiple pins but I don't think the library supports it.